# options has an unknown property 'prependData'. These properties are valid:

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

When running npm run dev in nuxt I get the following error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                                                                                              friendly-errors 14:26:26
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'prependData'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, additionalData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
```

People were saying you should change the loading options

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: '@import "@/scss/settings.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
```

and use prependData instead of data. But how do I do than in Nuxt?

Answer (score 2):

Change prependData to additionalData:

```
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: '@import "@/scss/settings.scss";'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to SASS 7.x (in my case 7.3.1)

In `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
  }
```